# Flask wondering how to improve IO performance

Tags: python, flask

I have an application that handles different files, I have 5 functions:

- http://serverIP:port/1
- http://serverIP:port/2
- http://serverIP:port/3
- http://serverIP:port/4
- http://serverIP:port/5

Each function receives a file (HTTP POST) saves to disk handles it and sends back a reply.

Many times it is the same file that is sent to all those URLs, what are my options to improve performance ?

Code looks something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file_ = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file_.filename)
    file_.save(file_path)
    <SOME INTERNAL LOGIC TO DO WITH THE FILE>
    return Response
```

Comment: Please add some code. What does your application look like currently? Also, pretty broad and relies on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your infra looks like, and what is the bottleneck. But broadly speaking, it will probably boils down to:

- hash the file you have to handle (either hash it on the server, or if you control the client, hash it on the client to save bandwidth)
- lookup in some kind of cache whether or not the response for this file is already available
- if it isn't available, handle the file, save the response in the cache and reply
- if it already is in the cache, reply directly.

If your application is single process, the cache can be a simple LRU dict (lookup `functools.lru_cache`), but if you need to spread the request on several processes, you will need to use an external cache (memcache and redis are probably the easiest to use)

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. The client can send a file only to function 1, to function 2,3,4,5 or to all of them.
This is what I meant by "sending the same files". But he almost never send the same file to the same function so cache won't help me much.

if sending a file to func 1 and than to func 2 it will be written 2 times to the server, this is what I thought to avoid.
Another thing I read is that Flask by itself is not the best Idea and should be considering running something like : nginx+gunicorn+flask to improve performance

Comment: The response is basically the same still: you will need to hash the file on the client, then send the hash to the server, then on the server, lookup the file in some kind of cache (in memory if you are running a single server process, in memcache, redis or other otherwise), then on the client, if the server does not yet have the file, send it, then call your function 1/2/3 endpoints with the hash only

Comment: And yes, using flask directly will of course lead to poor performances in production, you will need some kind of load balancing setup, with nginx/gunicorn for instance to spread the load across several processes. But this subject is way too broad for a SO question, please read some articles on the subject first